# How to find the max and min of a complex valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm assuming it's not as simple as just taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero, but we haven't gone over how to do this in class, and I have no clue how to do this in general for a function that isn't real valued. If you could just give me a hint on how to get started, I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Edit: The textbook also doesn't give any examples of how to do it in the chapter.

Comment: There is no natural order in the complex numbers, so we don’t have the notion of “being greater than” with complex numbers. The usual way to compare two complex numbers is through its modulus, which are real valued.

Comment: Right, they aren't an ordered field, so I can only tell how big they are using the modulus, or size function sqrt(X^2+y^2), but I don't really know how to apply this...

Comment: The modulus of what?  If your function is taking in values, you take the modulus, and outputting values, and you take the modulus, this is a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and you know how to minmax it.

Answer (score 0):

For a  complex function $f(x,y)=u+iv$, you can try taking the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of $f$ and setting it equal to zero. Then sign test intervals for different $x,y$.

Comment: Does that work in general? Can I always do that?

Comment: Don't see why it would not, just remember that the gradient is a vector-valued function, so checking for critical points would mean $|\nabla f(x,y)|=0$.